# Passed parameter between Fragment and Activity is null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have encountered such problem. Seems like I'm doing everything right but the received value of parameter is `null`. Would appreciate some help.

Its needed to pass index of item in GridView.
Here's Fragment class:

```
public class BoardsFragment extends Fragment{
private GridView gridView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), InfoActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("ItemID", i); //Optional parameters
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

I need to pass this `ItemID`. Here's where I receive that:

```
public class InfoActivity extends Activity {
String itemID;
TextView brand;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
    brand = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBrand);
    itemID = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("ItemID"); 
    brand.setText(itemID);
}
```

}

Don't know why but this `itemID` is null in this class. Any ideas?

Comment: Where the fragment is hosted? Does your activity exists and is being recalled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing values int then how can you get string in your activity.

update code

```
  myIntent.putExtra("ItemID", i+"");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot get string after passing integer so change this

```
itemID = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("ItemID");
```

to

```
itemID = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("ItemID");
```

Comment: add more information pointing to the mistake made by the op, to prevent flagging your answer to deletion.